# Cannot load files as modules

Tags: python

Here's my app directories structure

[image]

This is my "excel_import_tests.py" code

```
import unittest
import pandas
from nasdaq_info import nasdaq_loading


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_import_excel(self):
        nasdaq_dataframe = nasdaq_loading.loading_nasdaq_info_from_spreadsheet()

        self.assertEqual(nasdaq_dataframe.loc['ZVO', 'Sector'], 'ConsumerServices')
        self.assertEqual(nasdaq_dataframe.loc['STT', 'Name'], 'StateStreetCorporationCommonStock')
        self.assertEqual(nasdaq_dataframe['Name']['ZVO'], 'ZovioInc.CommonStock')
        self.assertEqual(nasdaq_dataframe['AEG']['Industry'], 'LifeInsurance')
        self.assertEqual(nasdaq_dataframe['AIN']['Sector'], 'BasicIndustries')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I'm trying to run him i got

> No module named 'nasdaq_info'

What's going wrong?

Comment: How are you invoking `excel_import_tests.py`?

Comment: @Brian i dont understand

Comment: Have you tried relative imports? `from .. import nasdaq_loading`

Comment: @Joscha I got "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package" error

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **init**.py in nasdaq_info directory? if not then try placing it there and it is just an empty file

Answer (score 0):

Try to add project root path to PYTHONPATH environment variable. In Linux you can do it e.g. with:

```
export PYTHONPATH=path/to/project/dir
```

Comment: @PawełDługosz which folder do you run this file from? Try to run this file from the root folder.

Comment: I was trying your pre-edit idea; how can I run file from root? i need to be in 'tests' folder to "python3 excel_import_tests.py"

Comment: `python3 -m  nasdaq_info.tests.excel_import_tests`

Comment: `python3 nasdaq_info/tests/excel_import_tests.py`. If it's windows, use another slashes

Comment: @dukkee yes yes, but it still doesnt work, I have completely no idea what's going wrong, Im going mad

Answer (score 0):

Probably Python assumes that `nasdaq_info/test` is you root directory. Try to set `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to path with your project.